# stack allocated memory versus dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c, memory-management

gcc 4.6.2 c89

I am just wondering what could cause more memory issues. For example, if you allocate a structure array on stack or if you was to allocate it dynamically on the heap.

Normally, I follow a simple rule. If the structure is only to be used in that function, then I allocate on the stack. However, if I need to refer to it somewhere else by keeping it in memory I would allocate dynamically.

The reason I asked this question as some of my memory was getting corrupted and I was told that I should allocate dynamically rather than on the stack for structure arrays. As stack memory has more chance of getting corrupted. However, if memory that is allocated dynamcially gets corrupted you can easily free it.

Does the above make sense to anyone?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say that any one way of allocating a structure has "more chance of corruption". Whatever is causing the corruption could happen just as easily however it's allocated.

I'd say you'd be better off fixing the source of the corruption: You can use gdb to put a breakpoint on write to the corrupted variable with `watch <varname>`. Alternatively, you can also put a breakpoint when you detect corruption, and then use [reverse debugging](http://www.jayconrod.com/cgi/view_post.py?28) to find where the corruption occurred.

---

Edit: There seems to be some confusion about the meaning of stack and [`static`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) allocation:

```
void foo() {
    int a[10]; // stack
    static int b[10]; // static

    int *c = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10); // dynamic on the heap
}
```

**Stack** variables are valid only during the lifetime of the function - once this function has returned, you can't expect the data at the location of `a` to still be valid. Sometimes these are called **local** or **automatic** variables.

**Static** variables inside a function are valid also outside the function - the data is kept around between function invocations. This means if you do this:

```
void foo() {
    static int a = 0;
    a++;
    printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

The number printed will increase by one on each invocation of `foo()`. Generally, functions don't have many variables declared as static, because static variables remember their last value from the last time the function was called - which is usually not the behaviour you want. It's possible this is what was meant by the person who told you that static variables have "more chance of being corrupted".

**Heap** variables are valid from when they're created to when they're `free()`d. This is also called **dynamic** allocation and is what you want if you're planning to return data to another part of the program (or if you want to specify the length of an array at runtime in C89).

---

Aside: `static` is confusing in that when applied to a function name or variable in global scope:

```
static void foo() { ... }
static int x;
```

it means "this function or variable is only visible inside this translation unit". I'm not sure why the `static` keyword has these two different meanings.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meet stack instead of static. Sorry.

Comment: @ant2009. No worries. If you're asking about stack/heap allocation, then I'd still say there's no difference from a corruption point of view, unless you're returning memory from that function (see H2CO3's answer). However, from your question it sounds like you're not referring to the memory elsewhere. In that case, I'd still say find the source of the corruption - if you like I can update my answer with a getting started guide to gdb?

Answer (score 3):

As a rule, never allocate statically, instead allocate on the stack when a data structure is local to a function. That makes it much easier to create re-entrant functions and avoid all sorts of issues.

(As an exception, allocating `const` data statically is no problem.)

**Edit**: ok, you meant stack allocation. In that case the rule you follow is sound practice. But neither stack nor heap allocation is any guarantee against memory corruption.

Comment: @nyarlathotep: I'm not sure what you mean, but static and stack allocation both exist in C and are different things.

Comment: Thought about it a little more and understand it now, sorry for the unjustified criticism ;)

Comment: "never allocate statically" is somewhat drastic, IMHO. You're right that you should use the stack, unless there's a good reason to do otherwise. Such a reason should be variables which should keep their values between calls to a function, be shared by several functions or buffers, whose pointer is returned from a functions. All these have their dangers, especially in multithreaded/reentrannt functions, but also have their uses.

Comment: @ugoren: Well, I did give one exception to the rule, and you're right there are other exceptions; but I always try to avoid all of those you mention. Having re-entrant functions makes debugging, testing and extending programs a lot easier.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meet stack instead of static. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

If you're worried about memory corruption, you should worry in both dynamic and static allocations. If you have a corruption, the difference is only what will be corrupted, but the result would be bad either way.

If you're worried about leaks, then static allocation makes life simple - you don't need to free it, so it can't leak.

But I think the main criterion should be whether or not static allocation makes you allocate too much.
With dynamic allocation, you can size your allocation based on your actual requirements, while with static allocations you may be force to allocate much more, up to some theoretical maximum. For example, if you want a structure per client, and support up to 1000 clients, you have to allocate 1000 structures in advance, even if in practice there are only 3 clients. With dynamic allocation, you allocate what you need, when you need it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meet stack instead of static. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

"Normally, I follow a simple rule. If the structure is only to be used in that function, then I allocate statically. However, if I need to refer to it somewhere else by keeping it in memory I would allocate dynamically."

Correct, you're doing it well.

Explanation: when you allocate memory statically, on the stack/heap/whichever your system uses when inside a function, that memory will be available until the function returns. If you pass it to another function, it's valid, as if e. g. function_a created the array/structure and called function_b, function_a haven't returned yet, so the array is valid. So is the following:

```
int function_b(char *buf); /* whatever it does */

int function_a() {
    char array[30];
    /* fill "array" */
    function_b(array); /* valid as this is yet inside this function */
    return 0;
}
```

But this memory is deallocated when function_a returns (so that's why you don't have to worry about statically allocated memory: it's not *really* statically allocated, the system frees it automagically after the function returns). Thus, the following would be incorrect and may cause runtime errors (e. g. segmentation violation or similar):

```
char *function_a_segfaulty() {
   char array[30];
   do_some_stuff();
   return array; /* INCORRECT: array is now invalid, as the function has returned */
}
```

That's the case when you need malloc()'ing a buffer, and returning it. Malloc() asks the OS for memory and returns a function-independent pointer to its beginning, so functions pass and that memory is *still valid*. The above example has to be done like this:

```
char *function_a_correct() {
   char *array = malloc(30);
   do_some_stuff();
   return array; /* correct */
}
```

But in this case, you have to think about freeing that array. A common practice is to document that this function's return value has to be free()'d and let the caller of the function do it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think you're confusing stack and static. Memory defined as `static` is still valid when the function returns - but variables on the stack aren't.

Comment: Sorry if it's unclear, but I'm not speaking about symbols declared with the "static" C keyword. I'm referring to local function variables  here.

Comment: Then you shouldn't call it "static allocation" :) I don't think your answer is addressing the question.

Comment: OK, sorry :) I sincerely thought that he wasn't referring to the literal 'static' keyword.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meet stack instead of static. Sorry.

Comment: @H2CO3 No worries - you had the right way to address it after all :) If you change "statically" to "on the stack", I'll give you a +1.